# How to use a fixture in mark.parametrize in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a scenario like below:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[5, 10])
def get_data(request):
    data = []
    for i in range(request.param):
        data.append((i, 2))
    return data


@pytest.mark.parametrize(('test_input','expected'), get_data)
def test_data_types(test_input, expected):
    assert (test_input%expected) == 0
```

but i get an error that " TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable". How to achieve my goal. I read that we cant use fixture as an argument in parametrized test function but i want some alternative.

Comment: `pytest` doesn't support using fixtures as parameters in `mark.parametrize`, see [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349).

Comment: That is why i asked this question. I asked for an alternative

Comment: The alternative is to not use fixtures as parameters. Use variables or plain functions.

Answer (score 4):

As hoefling mentioned, you can use a plain function to get data. Here's a simple example.
I have a get_data() function in each of my test files, which pull data from different sheets of an excel file.

```
from utils.excel_utils import ExcelUtils
import pytest


def get_data():
    data = ExcelUtils("inputData.xlsx", "Session").get_input_rows()
    for row in data:
        yield row


@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", get_data())
def test_session(test_input):
    print(test_input)
    assert "session" in test_input
```

Comment: Hi, In my case that function I want to call in the parametize is using fixtures and I am not able to use those fixtures in the function call. Is there a work around?

Comment: @GopinathS - Hi, it might be good idea to ask a new question with more details.

Comment: Yes, I did post one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158867/pytest-use-a-fixture-that-uses-another-fixture-as-input-to-parameterize-unit-te. Haven't received any answers yet. Is that something you could help with?